# How to access the call stack of a DOORS DXL script?

Tags: assert, ibm-doors

In order to write a proper `assert(bool)` function for testing my DXL programs, I would love to be able to print the call stack if the boolean is false.

Can anybody help me with either getting access to the call stack or finding a handy [assertion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assertion_%28software_development%29) function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There really isn't a lot of information regarding this type of debugging available in DXL. I have seen some 3rd party DXL Compilers on the market (Sodius makes a good one) that might help or you can try to write your own debug using the information in the `Error handling` section of the DXL Reference Manual.

Comment: Ok, I there are no hidden functions then using the output of 'dxlHere()' will do.